# Saving The RDD pair in particular format in the output file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I have a JavaPairRDD lets say data of type

```
<Integer,List<Integer>>
```

when i do data.saveAsTextFile("output")
The output will contain the data in the following format:

(1,[1,2,3,4])

etc...

I want something like this in the output file :

1   1,2,3,4

```
i.e. 1\t1,2,3,4
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand what's happening here. You have an `RDD[T,U]` where T and U are some obj types, read it as RDD of Tuple of T and U. On this RDD when you call `saveAsTextFile()`, it essentially converts each element of RDD to string, hence the text file is generated as output.

Now, how is an object of some type T converted to a string? By calling the toString() on it. This is the reason why you have [] representing the List, and () representing the Tuple as whole.

Solution, map each element in your RDD to a string as per your format. I'm not that familiar with the Java Syntax but with Scala I'll do something like,

```
rdd.map(e=>s"${e._1}\t${e._2.mkString(",")}")
```

Where mkString concatenates a collection using some delimiter.

Let me know if this helped. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks i will do this