# Write JavaPairRdd to Csv

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, key-value, java-pair-rdd

JavaPairRdd has `saveAsTextfile` function, with which you can save data in a text format.

However what I need is to save the data as CSV file, so I can use it later with Neo4j.

My question is:

How to save the JavaPairRdd 's  data in CSV format? Or is there a way to transform the rdd from :

```
Key   Value
Jack  [a,b,c]
```

to:

```
Key  value
 Jack  a
 Jack  b
 Jack  c
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398795/saving-the-rdd-pair-in-particular-format-in-the-output-file) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `flatMapValues` function on your JavaPairRdd: `Pass each value in the key-value pair RDD through a flatMap function without changing the keys; this also retains the original RDD's partitioning.`

Just by returning the value it will create a line per element in the input lists preserving the keys.

```
  // In Java
  JavaPairRDD<Object, List<String>> input = ...;
  JavaPairRDD<Object, String> output = input.flatMapValues((Function<List<String>, Iterable<String>>) Functions.identity());
```

Comment: can you answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283041/transform-java-pair-rdd-to-rdd) please